# Write protect an USB key by firmware

Tags: usb, key, firmware

I need to write-protect USB keys to distribute, in the same way as DVD are (no modification allowed, even partition formatting). It seems that the only way is to change the firmware of the key. Are there ways to do it either manually or do companies offer this service ?

Answer (score 0):

I have only heard of two ways to write protect usb keys.

NEXCOPY DOES THIS  http://www.nexcopy.com/usb-duplicator/

I also hear if you find the right SMI usb you can do it yourself!  READ ABOUT THAT BELOW http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/97---write-protect-or-make-a-cd-dvd-partition-on-a-flash-drive